# different behavior of changing config by extjs.apply

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.define('extjs.example.mypanel',{
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align : 'stretch',
        pack  : 'start',
     },
    initComponent: function(config) {
        Ext.apply(this.subpanel,{
        html:'panel changed',
        listeners:{
                click: function(){alert('hi');},
                element: 'body'
        }
    } 
        );
        Ext.apply(this,{
            items: [
                this.subpanel,
                {html:'panel 2', height:150},
                {html:'panel 3', height:150}
            ]
        } 
        );
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    subpanel:Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
        html:'panel 1', 
        height:150
    })
```

}
);

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
Ext.create('extjs.example.mypanel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height:500,
    width: 500
});
```

});

it's code. I want to study how to use Ext.apply. here, I change two configuration by this method. one is html and another is listeners.
but I found that the html changed works. but the listeners don't.

My question is that:
1) what is my problem? I did wrong or some config can't be changed by Ext.apply?
2）if I did wrong, how to correct it？
3）if some config can't use Ext.apply? is there any rules or doc about it?

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.apply` doesn't assign listeners. It just copies all the properties of config to the specified object. In your example `this.subpanel` is instance of `Ext.panel.Panel` and what you can do is to pass a config object instead:

```
subpanel: {
    xtype: 'panel',
    html: 'panel 1',
    height: 150
}
```